# InvalidArgumenterror Incompatiple shapes in Keras model.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

When trying model.fit i receive a InvalidArgumentError with a note of Incompatible shapes.

I am trying to predict age and gender based on the UTKFace images form Kaggle. I created a basic CNN with modified ImageDataGenerators

```
df3 = df2.copy()

def process(filename):
    image = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\DE-KYasar\Downloads\archive\utkface_aligned_cropped\UTKFace\{x}".format(x = filename), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (200, 200))
    image = image.astype("float32")
    image = image / 255.0
    return image
df3["file"] = df3["file"].apply(lambda x: process(x))

df3.head()
```

[image: Dataframe structure]

I made some preprocessing, created the model and the datagenerators

```
X = df3["file"]
ages_train = np.array(df3["Age"])
genders_train = np.array(df3["Gender"])


X = np.array(X.tolist())
X = X.reshape(-1, 200, 200, 1)

train_images, test_images, train_ages1, test_ages1, train_genders1, test_genders1 = train_test_split(
    X, ages_train, genders_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

train_ages = np.asarray(train_ages1).astype('float32').reshape((-1,1))
test_ages = np.asarray(test_ages1).astype('float32').reshape((-1,1))

train_genders = np.asarray(train_genders1).astype('float32').reshape((-1,1))
test_genders = np.asarray(test_genders1).astype('float32').reshape((-1,1))

image_width = X.shape[1]
image_height = X.shape[2]
image_channels = X.shape[3]  # Set to 1 for grayscale images
num_images = X.shape[0]

input_layer = Input(shape=(image_height, image_width, image_channels))

conv1 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(input_layer)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(pool1)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
flatten = Flatten()(pool2)

dense1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(flatten)
dense2 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(dense1)

age_output = Dense(1, activation='linear', name='age_output')(dense2)
gender_output = Dense(1, activation='softmax', name='gender_output')(dense2)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[age_output, gender_output])

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              loss={'age_output': 'mse', 'gender_output': 'binary_crossentropy'},
              metrics={'age_output': 'mae', 'gender_output': 'binary_accuracy'})

image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True
)

# Example settings for the age output
age_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True
)

# Example settings for the gender output
gender_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True
)


train_image_data_generator = image_generator.flow(
    train_images,  # The images as an array or generator
    batch_size=64,
    shuffle=True  # Set to True if you want to shuffle the data during training
)

train_age_data_generator = age_generator.flow(
    train_images,  # The images as an array or generator
    train_ages,  # The age labels as a list or array
    batch_size=64,
    shuffle=True  # Set to True if you want to shuffle the data during training
)

train_gender_data_generator = gender_generator.flow(
    train_images,  # The images as an array or generator
    train_genders,  # The gender labels as a list or array
    batch_size=64,
    shuffle=True  # Set to True if you want to shuffle the data during training
)


def multi_output_data_generator(image_data_generator, age_data_generator, gender_data_generator):
    while True:
        # Get the next batch of images and labels for each output
        images = image_data_generator.next()
        ages = age_data_generator.next()
        genders = gender_data_generator.next()
        
        yield images, {'age_output': ages, 'gender_output': genders}

train_steps_per_epoch = train_images.shape[0] // 64
val_steps = train_images.shape[0] // 64
```

But now if i want to fit the model with

```
model.fit(
    multi_output_data_generator(train_image_data_generator, train_age_data_generator, train_gender_data_generator),
    steps_per_epoch=train_steps_per_epoch,
    validation_data=(test_images, {'age_output': test_ages, 'gender_output': test_genders}),
    validation_steps=val_steps,
    epochs=2
)
```

i receive the following Error

[image: Error Screenshot]

Where can i change to code to get ir unning? I can imagine it is a problem of shapes but not sure.

Thanks in advance!